# ValueError: time data '2020-07-19 20:36:04' does not match format '%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'

Tags: python

I am new to Python, I tried to convert a String formatted like '2020-***7***-19 20:36:04' to datetime in python 3.8 with code like below:

`tempDate = '2020-7-19 20:36:04' datetime.strptime(tempDate, '%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')`

I got error message shows like 'Can not convert non-zero padded string to datetime'

so I formatted datetime string to 2020-***07***-19 20:36:04
then I coded below:

```
tempDate = '2020-7-19 20:36:04'
dateAndTime = tempDate .split(' ')
ymd = dateAndTime[0].split('-')
month = ymd[1].zfill(2)
day = ymd[2].zfill(2)
tempDate = ymd[0] + '-' + month+ '-' + day + ' ' + dateAndTime[-1]
postDate = datetime.strptime(tempDate, '%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

then I got error

```
File "C:\Python38\lib\_strptime.py", line 568, in _strptime_datetime
tt, fraction, gmtoff_fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)
File "C:\Python38\lib\_strptime.py", line 349, in _strptime
raise ValueError("time data %r does not match format %r" %
ValueError: time data '2020-07-19 20:36:04' does not match format '%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
```

I don't have a good search skill...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
tempDate = '2020-7-19 20:36:04'
dateAndTime = tempDate.split(' ')
ymd = dateAndTime[0].split('-')
month = ymd[1].zfill(2)
day = ymd[2].zfill(2)
tempDate = ymd[0] + '-' + month+ '-' + day + ' ' + dateAndTime[-1]
postDate = datetime.strptime(tempDate, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

you have to use `%Y` instead of `%y` because `%y` is for the last two digits, without the century like 00, 01, 02.

Read more about `strptime`:

- https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/datetime/strptime

Comment: Thanks for your help~~~!
Do you know any better way to convert none-zero padded string to a datetime?
I just thought these codes kinda stupid.

Comment: @Hamil You could use `%-m` for month as a not zero padded string, just decimal. The website explained that as well you should take a look

Comment: Thanks again, its really helped!
I don't even know how I searched for solutions before. I have never seen the option such as '-m', '-y' in search results..